# Showing $\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is a bases for $\mathbb{R}_{\text{usual}}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Show that the collection $\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{Q}} := \{(p, q) \subseteq \mathbb{R} : p, q \in \mathbb{Q}, p < q \}$ is a basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Solution:
We know that $\mathcal{B} = \{ (a, b) \subseteq \Bbb{R} : a < b \}$ generates the usual topology, if we show $\forall x \in B \subseteq \mathcal{B} \exists$ A $ \in \mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{Q}} : x \in A \subseteq B$ then this would imply that they generate the same topology. Let (a,b) be any set of $\mathcal{B}$ if a,b are rationals we are done, if they are irrationals choose the largest rational number $p  \leq a$ and smallest rational $q \geq b$, there existence is guaranteed by the properties of the $\mathbb{R}$ (every interval contains rationals and irrationals arbitrarily close to each other) then $\forall x \in (p,q) \ \exists \  (a,b) : x \in (a,b) \subseteq (p,q)$ and hence, the generate the same topology.

Comment: You might run into trouble by saying "largest rational number" and "smallest rational number" considering that the rationals are dense. Instead, try constructing a decreasing sequence $a_n$ of rationals that converges to $a$, and an increasing sequence $b_n$ of rationals that converges to be. Then, the union of the sequence of intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ should converge to $(a,b)$. Openness is preserved by arbitrary union, so $(a,b)$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier: let $(a,b)$ be an arbitary open interval, and $x \in A$. Then both $(a,x)$ and $(x,b)$ are non-empty open intervals, so they both contain a rational point, say $p$ in the former, $q$ in the latter. Then $x \in (p,q) \subset (a,b)$ as required.